# Configure TableView Cells With A Set

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm not sure how to configure my custom cells to use a set in a tableView. I want to be able to display my cells but I get the syntax error **Cannot call value of non-function type 'Set'** in my cellForRowAt with my itemFav, how would I configure my current index to use a set?

```
var favSet = Set<CurrentPlayers>()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "favcell", for: indexPath) as! FavCell
    let itemFav = favSet(indexPath.row) //How do I configure this to a set

    cell.update(with: itemFav)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You probably want `favSet[indexPath.row]` but this cannot work because a Set is unordered. Better use an Array for the data source.

Comment: First find the `CurrentPlayers` object associated with `indexPath.row`, then see if `itemFav.contains(theAssociatedPlayer)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I understand, you need access by index. Try this:

```swift
favSet[favSet.index(favSet.startIndex, offsetBy: indexPath.row)]
```

Comment: Can you explain, why did you downgrade?